# What is the .optimizer package in Pytorch?

Tags: optimization, pytorch

I am trying to write my own optimizer for pytorch and am looking at the source code https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/sgd.html#SGD

to get started. When I try to run the code for the SGD, I get an error on the line
`from .optimizer import Optimizer, required`. I've searched everywhere but I'm not sure where to obtain the .optimizer package. Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `import .optimizer` means import `optimizer.py` from the same directory as the current .py file, so this [file](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/22a34bcf4e5eaa348f0117c414c3dd760ec64b13/torch/optim/optimizer.py)